# what is a collective term for things as screening failures, no response and drop-outs

Tags: descriptive-statistics

Hello wondering what is a collective term (in terms of statistics) for things as screening failures, no response and drop-outs?

Answer (score 0):

Loss of participants during a study or experiment is often called [attrition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attrition_(research)).